# Go times out on sleep but not on busy-wait

Tags: concurrency, go, timeout, thread-sleep, busy-waiting

In Go, I can use `time.After` to time out a sleeping function, but I can't do the same to a function that is busy-waiting (or working). The following code returns `timed out` after one second, and then hangs.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        sleepChan := make(chan int)
        go sleep(sleepChan)
        select {
        case sleepResult := <-sleepChan:
                fmt.Println(sleepResult)
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
                fmt.Println("timed out")
        }

        busyChan := make(chan int)
        go busyWait(busyChan)
        select {
        case busyResult := <-busyChan:
                fmt.Println(busyResult)
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
                fmt.Println("timed out")
        }
}

func sleep(c chan<- int) {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        c <- 0
}

func busyWait(c chan<- int) {
        for {
        }
        c <- 0
}
```

Why doesn't the timeout fire in the second case, and what alternative do I need to use to interrupt working goroutines?

Comment: `for{}` is pretty much never what you want in any piece of software. Have you tried it with something valid?

Comment: I agree. It doesn't seem a very useful question because tight busy-looping like this shouldn't ever be needed. Anything that allows interaction with the goroutine scheduler (using channel and timers in particular) will allow it to swap, and therefore the problem you raised won't really exist.

Comment: Good question. It was initially a primality check but I replaced it with a busy wait to simplify the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for {}` statement is an infinite loop which monopolizes a single processor. Set [`runtime.GOMAXPROCS`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) to 2 or more to allow the timer to run.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))
    sleepChan := make(chan int)
    go sleep(sleepChan)
    select {
    case sleepResult := <-sleepChan:
        fmt.Println(sleepResult)
    case <-time.After(time.Second):
        fmt.Println("timed out")
    }

    busyChan := make(chan int)
    go busyWait(busyChan)
    select {
    case busyResult := <-busyChan:
        fmt.Println(busyResult)
    case <-time.After(time.Second):
        fmt.Println("timed out")
    }
}

func sleep(c chan<- int) {
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    c <- 0
}

func busyWait(c chan<- int) {
    for {
    }
    c <- 0
}
```

Output (4 CPU processor):

```
1
4
timed out
timed out
```

Comment: Thank you! I was under the misimpression that the loop would eventually yield to the scheduler. Apparently that doesn't happen without calling `runtime.Gosched()`.